# How to manually fill a form field after being submitted using a value passed to the URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-file-upload

I have this form where the user has to upload a file(receipt) and then connect that file with a foreign key. I have created a simple form which takes the file, and it is working fine too. But, I have to save that file in the database, along with a foreign key to another model. Right now my model just has the file as relation and the foreign key. My form has just the field for the file upload because I obviously do not want the user to select what foreign key it is supposed to be. I want that foreign key to be filled automatically with the value given in the URL. I am calling the function like so:

`href="{% url 'suppliers:model_form_upload' quiz.id %}"`

where I am getting the `quiz.id` correctly.

This is my model:

```
class Uploaded_pod(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='pods/')
    lr_connected = models.ForeignKey(LR, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lr_pod')
```

---

### What I Tried

This is my views.py function:

```
def pod_upload (request, pk):
    lr_object = get_object_or_404(LR, id=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadPODform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.lr_connected = lr_object
        form.save()

        if form.is_valid():
            form.lr_connected = lr_object
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UploadPODform()
        form.lr_connected = lr_object


    return render(request, 'classroom/suppliers/model_form_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

As you can see, I am trying to fill the `form.lr_connected` part with the object I just filtered using the pk value passed in the URL.

This is my form:

```
class UploadPODform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Uploaded_pod
        fields = ('document',)
```

I printed the object `lr_object` also, and it was working just fine. But, when I go the the page to upload a file, it tells me that

> null value in column "lr_connected_id" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (10, pods/csv_BET4hl8.svg, null).

Which clearly mens my lr_connected field was not filled by the object I tried to pass it.

Is this possible?? Is there a better way ???

I followed this [guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html) to upload files. Is this what is complicating the issue?

This my html rendered  to:

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>


    </form>

    <p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Here you can see I added print statement, and it is showing that in my terminal that it found the lr_object with 5 as the ID.

[image: proof]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the value to the instance, not the form.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadPODform(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.lr_connected = lr_object
        obj.save()
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am getting the same error.  `null value in column "lr_connected_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (14, pods/postgres_public_django_migrations.csv, null).` I even tried to add the field `lr_connected` to forms, and then it just rendered a dropdown with a few objects.

Comment: That's not possible if `lr_object` is the object you got at the start of the view. Please show the full traceback (as an edit to the question).

Comment: Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html `form` tag.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you are still trying to save the form outside of the is_valid block. I don't know why you are doing that. Remove those two lines before is_valid.